# Verify pdf signature with node.js

Tags: node.js, pdf

I need to verify the signature of a signed pdf document using node.js
so far i've been trying to use [@ninja-labs/verify-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ninja-labs/verify-pdf) which should have a simple solution for this exact issue. However the only results i get is undefined.

Can anyone help me verify signature of a signed pdf document? Solution does not have to include ninja'labs.

A different approach is to use the 'getCertificatesInfoFromPDF' function, also from ninja-labs/verify-pdf.

This method should give men the option to return "issuedTo", but instead i'm met with "VerifyPDFError: Failed byte range verification" no matter the sice of the pdf document.

```
const verifyPDF = require('@ninja-labs/verify-pdf');
const signedPdfBuffer = fs.readFileSync('signed.pdf');

const {
    verified,
    authenticity,
    integrity,
    expired,
    meta
} = verifyPDF(signedPdfBuffer);

console.log("verified: "+verified)
```